# Dynamically insert div(div no always very from 0-100) into a fixed size div : Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a fixed size div in which dynamically div will come using ng-repeat. The insider div in such a way like if only one div come then it should take size(height and width) 100%. If 2 then 25%.Here is a screenshot I pest.Please have a look. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What is your question?  Please include code in your question  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: have you a max number of div or it can be infinite ? Is there only 3 different size ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a ng-class and change class depending of your number of div

First create your  different css class with a container.

**CSS**

```
.container{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  border:solid 1px black;  
}

/* use for all child */
.child{
  display:inline-table;
}

/*For 2x2 */
.deux{
  background-color:red;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
}

/* 3x3 */
.trois{
  background-color:blue;
  width:33.3%;
  height:33.3%;
}

/* 4x4 */
.quatre{
  background-color:yellow;
  width:25%;
  height:25%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
       <div  ng-repeat="x in i" class="child" ng-class="{'deux':(i.length<=4),'trois':(i.length>4 && i.length<=9),'quatre':(i.length>9)}">
       {{x}}
       </div>
  </div>
```

You can try to change the array in my example :

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/4874/)**

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
.big{

     height: 300px;
     width: 300px;
     overflow: auto;
     background: #DAE8ED;
```

}

```
.small{
    float:left;
    background: #EDDFDA;
}
```

Controller,

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){

  $scope.numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
  var width = 300/Math.ceil(Math.sqrt($scope.numbers.length)) + 'px';
  $scope.customStyle={'height':width, 'width':width};
});
```

HTML,

```
<body ng-controller='Ctrl'>
    <div class='big'>
     <div class='small' ng-repeat="n in numbers" ng-style='customStyle'></div>
</div>
```